# Registred user can't add to cart. Prestashop

Tags: authentication, prestashop, addition, cart, avalara

I have a big problem.

This problem have been talked quite a few times, but I can't get it to work...

I've tryed everything suggested on Prestashop forum (also posted, but still no reply):
1. Changing shop domain and SSL.
First I had it as growmundocannabico.com (in both places, didn't work), changed to www.growmundocannabico.com and still didn't solve the problem.

2. Cleared coockies and all the browser history (firefox), didn't solve the problem. P.D. Doesn't work on other browser's as well. Tested on Chrome and IE10.
3. Tryed modifying .htcacess file, didn't help...

Here is the shop url: www.growmundocannabico.com

I have changed define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', false); to define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true); in config/define.inc.php to show errors. And the result is in attachment.

Can anyone explain me in simple why what does it mean and what I should do to fix it??? Because the programing is not my strong side.

Thanks,[image]

Here is the code: I don't understand
1. the line 20 is a *
2. No php is not closed, should it be that way?

```
<?php
/*
* 2007-2012 PrestaShop
*
* NOTICE OF LICENSE
*
* This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
* that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
* It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
* http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
* If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
* obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
* to license@prestashop.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
*
* DISCLAIMER
*
* Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade PrestaShop to newer
* versions in the future. If you wish to customize PrestaShop for your
* needs please refer to http://www.prestashop.com for more information.
*
*  @author PrestaShop SA <contact@prestashop.com>
*  @copyright  2007-2012 PrestaShop SA
*  @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
*  International Registered Trademark & Property of PrestaShop SA
*/


class TaxCore extends ObjectModel
{
    /** @var string Name */
    public $name;

    /** @var float Rate (%) */
    public $rate;

    /** @var bool active state */
    public $active;

    /** @var boolean true if the tax has been historized */
    public $deleted = 0;

    /**
     * @see ObjectModel::$definition
     */
    public static $definition = array(
        'table' => 'tax',
        'primary' => 'id_tax',
        'multilang' => true,
        'fields' => array(
            'rate' =>           array('type' => self::TYPE_FLOAT, 'validate' => 'isFloat', 'required' => true),
            'active' =>         array('type' => self::TYPE_BOOL),
            'deleted' =>        array('type' => self::TYPE_BOOL),

            // Lang fields
            'name' =>           array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'lang' => true, 'validate' => 'isGenericName', 'required' => true, 'size' => 32),
        ),
    );


    protected static $_product_country_tax = array();
    protected static $_product_tax_via_rules = array();

    protected   $webserviceParameters = array(
        'objectsNodeName' => 'taxes',
    );

    public function delete()
    {
        /* Clean associations */
        TaxRule::deleteTaxRuleByIdTax((int)$this->id);

        if ($this->isUsed())
            return $this->historize();
        else
            return parent::delete();
    }

    /**
     * Save the object with the field deleted to true
     *
     *  @return bool
     */
    public function historize()
    {
        $this->deleted = true;
        return parent::update();
    }

    public function toggleStatus()
    {
        if (parent::toggleStatus())
            return $this->_onStatusChange();

        return false;
    }

    public function update($nullValues = false)
    {
        if (!$this->deleted && $this->isUsed())
        {
            $historized_tax = new Tax($this->id);
            $historized_tax->historize();

            // remove the id in order to create a new object
            $this->id = 0;
            $this->add();

            // change tax id in the tax rule table
            TaxRule::swapTaxId($historized_tax->id, $this->id);
        } else if (parent::update($nullValues))
                return $this->_onStatusChange();

        return false;
    }

    protected function _onStatusChange()
    {
        if (!$this->active)
            return TaxRule::deleteTaxRuleByIdTax($this->id);

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if the tax is used in an order details
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isUsed()
    {
        return Db::getInstance()->getValue('
        SELECT `id_tax`
        FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'order_detail_tax`
        WHERE `id_tax` = '.(int)$this->id
        );
    }

    /**
    * Get all available taxes
    *
    * @return array Taxes
    */
    public static function getTaxes($id_lang = false, $active_only = true)
    {
        $sql = new DbQuery();
        $sql->select('t.id_tax, t.rate');
        $sql->from('tax', 't');
        $sql->where('t.`deleted` != 1');

        if ($id_lang)
        {
            $sql->select('tl.name, tl.id_lang');
            $sql->leftJoin('tax_lang', 'tl', 't.`id_tax` = tl.`id_tax` AND tl.`id_lang` = '.(int)$id_lang);
            $sql->orderBy('`name` ASC');
        }

        if ($active_only)
            $sql->where('t.`active` = 1');

        return Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->executeS($sql);
    }

    public static function excludeTaxeOption()
    {
        static $ps_tax = null;
        if ($ps_tax === null)
            $ps_tax = Configuration::get('PS_TAX');

        return !$ps_tax;
    }

    /**
    * Return the tax id associated to the specified name
    *
    * @param string $tax_name
    * @param boolean $active (true by default)
    */
    public static function getTaxIdByName($tax_name, $active = 1)
    {
        $tax = Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->getRow('
            SELECT t.`id_tax`
            FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'tax` t
            LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'tax_lang` tl ON (tl.id_tax = t.id_tax)
            WHERE tl.`name` = \''.pSQL($tax_name).'\' '.
            ($active == 1 ? ' AND t.`active` = 1' : ''));

        return $tax ? (int)($tax['id_tax']) : false;
    }

    /**
    * Returns the ecotax tax rate
    *
    * @param id_address
    * @return float $tax_rate
    */
    public static function getProductEcotaxRate($id_address = null)
    {
        $address = Address::initialize($id_address);

        $tax_manager = TaxManagerFactory::getManager($address, (int)Configuration::get('PS_ECOTAX_TAX_RULES_GROUP_ID'));
        $tax_calculator = $tax_manager->getTaxCalculator();

        return $tax_calculator->getTotalRate();
    }

    /**
    * Returns the carrier tax rate
    *
    * @param id_address
    * @return float $tax_rate
    */
    public static function getCarrierTaxRate($id_carrier, $id_address = null)
    {
        $address = Address::initialize($id_address);
        $id_tax_rules = (int)Carrier::getIdTaxRulesGroupByIdCarrier((int)$id_carrier);

        $tax_manager = TaxManagerFactory::getManager($address, $id_tax_rules);
        $tax_calculator = $tax_manager->getTaxCalculator();

        return $tax_calculator->getTotalRate();
    }

    /**
     * Return the product tax rate using the tax rules system
     *
     * @param integer $id_product
     * @param integer $id_country
     * @return Tax
     *
     * @deprecated since 1.5
     */
    public static function getProductTaxRateViaRules($id_product, $id_country, $id_state, $zipcode)
    {
        Tools::displayAsDeprecated();

        if (!isset(self::$_product_tax_via_rules[$id_product.'-'.$id_country.'-'.$id_state.'-'.$zipcode]))
        {
            $tax_rate = TaxRulesGroup::getTaxesRate((int)Product::getIdTaxRulesGroupByIdProduct((int)$id_product), (int)$id_country, (int)$id_state, $zipcode);
            self::$_product_tax_via_rules[$id_product.'-'.$id_country.'-'.$zipcode] = $tax_rate;
        }

        return self::$_product_tax_via_rules[$id_product.'-'.$id_country.'-'.$zipcode];
    }

    /**
     * Returns the product tax
     *
     * @param integer $id_product
     * @param integer $id_country
     * @return Tax
     */
    public static function getProductTaxRate($id_product, $id_address = null, Context $context = null)
    {
        if ($context == null)
            $context = Context::getContext();

        $address = Address::initialize($id_address);
        $id_tax_rules = (int)Product::getIdTaxRulesGroupByIdProduct($id_product, $context);

        $tax_manager = TaxManagerFactory::getManager($address, $id_tax_rules);
        $tax_calculator = $tax_manager->getTaxCalculator();

        return $tax_calculator->getTotalRate();
    }
}
```

Here is the override.

```
<?php

class Tax extends TaxCore
{

    /**
     * Return the product tax
     *
     * @param integer $id_product
     * @param integer $id_address
     * @return Tax Rate
     */
    public static function getProductTaxRate($id_product, $id_address = null, $getCarrierRate = false)
    {
        include_once(_PS_ROOT_DIR_.'/modules/avalaratax/avalaratax.php');

        /* Instanciate the Avalara module and check if active */
        $avalara = new AvalaraTax();
        if (!$avalara->active)
            return parent::getProductTaxRate($id_product, $id_address, $getCarrierRate);

        /* With Avalara, we disable the tax for non logged users */
        if (!(int)$id_address)
            return 0.;

        $region = Db::getInstance()->getValue('SELECT s.`iso_code`
                                    FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'address a
                                    LEFT JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'state s ON (s.`id_state` = a.`id_state`)
                                    WHERE a.`id_address` = '.(int)$id_address);

        /* If the Merchant does not want to calculate taxes outside his state and we are outside the state, we return 0 */
        if ((!empty($region) && $region != Configuration::get('AVALARATAX_STATE') && !Configuration::get('AVALARATAX_TAX_OUTSIDE')))
            return 0.;

        return (float)Db::getInstance()->getValue('SELECT ac.`tax_rate`
        FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'avalara_'.($getCarrierRate ? 'carrier' : 'product').'_cache ac
        WHERE ac.`id_'.($getCarrierRate ? 'carrier' : 'product').'` = '.(int)$id_product.'
        AND ac.`region` = \''.pSQL($region).'\'');
    }

    public static function getCarrierTaxRate($id_carrier, $id_address = NULL)
    {
        return (float)self::getProductTaxRate($id_carrier, $id_address, true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error seems to be in your override 'Tax' class. What does it do, and why is it there? It is not part of standard Prestashop, so the error most likely lies there. As the error message says, something in that code calls getProductTaxRate() with an invalid parameter.

Comment: I've deleted the taxes witch were create. Left only the original ones... And still the problem remains... :( it is clear that it something strange with the taxes. I also noticed that when I log in, the tax disspears.. What is going on??? Tax is set, the rule is also set for Spain...

Comment: Have you removed the override class?

Comment: where can I find it?, I'm lost at the moment... I'm searching for solution for several hours now...

Comment: It's in override/classes in your Prestashop installation, as the error message indicates.

Comment: That's not the override class, is it? That looks like the standard included TaxCore class.

Comment: Sorry, Override is posted now.

Comment: I don't know where did the override came from. Should I delete it??